# session_decode() doesn't retrieve the right $_SESSION informations from CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have an ecommerce built with CodeIgniter 3 and a dashboard site built in php.
I would that the user logged on the ecommerce, would be already logged also in the personal dashboard.
In the ecommerce, there is a button to pass to the dashboard. This button calls the file of the dashboard (APS) named /APS/index.php.
In this file I put:

```
<?php session_start();
require_once("config.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['client']) || empty($_SESSION['client'])) {

    if (isset($_COOKIE['ci_session']) && !empty($_COOKIE['ci_session'])) {

// Check connection

        $sql = "SELECT `data` FROM `ci_sessions` WHERE id=" . "'" . $_COOKIE['ci_session'] . "'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $first_arr = '';

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            // output data of each row

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                $first_arr = explode(';', $row['data']);

            }

            $res = '';

            foreach ($first_arr as $v) {

                if (strpos($v, 'customer_id') !== false) {

                    $res = explode('|', $v);

                }

            }

            $conn->close();

            $_SESSION['client'] = unserialize($res[1]);

        } else {

            $_SESSION['client'] = '';

        }

    }

}

if(isset($_SESSION['client']) && !empty($_SESSION['client'])){  header('location:account.php'); $x=$client->get($_SESSION['client']);  $_SESSION['client']=$x[0]; exit; }
```

The problem is that in $_SESSION['client'] there is not the user informations. There are all the users in the user table and then it passes the first element of this list to the next page, /APS/account.php, showing the dashboard always for the first user of the user table.

How can I do?

ps. I printed some variables. The $sql statement is correct, and in $res there is the right customer_id of the logged user. The unserialize() function - I already tried the session_decode() function, but with the same result - return 1 (true), but this is not what I want.

Comment: Probably not a good idea trying to integrate a Codeigniter (CI) based website with one written with procedural PHP, Your problem is due to the way CI handles sessions. The associated session cookie will be using config setting from CI. In addition, CI has uses a custom implementation (driver) to handle PHP sessions..

Comment: so I can't find a solution? :(

Comment: They read from the same DB. So I thought that if I was able to retrieve the session cookie, I would be able to retrieve also the related user in a correct way. I see the customer_id in query response.

Comment: Cookies were encrypted. so you have to decrypt using CI session function and move to normal cookie

Comment: How can pratically do this?

Comment: Rewrite the dashboard using codeigniter.

Comment: Haha :D I can't do this! I know it would be the best solution, but I can't